# How I can count the space between left border and begin of a text in the text-align: centered div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-align

```
<div style='text-align: center; width: 300px'>test me</div>
```

so I need a margin-left px from the left side to the first letter of the string in div?

Comment: Why on earth would you need to do that? What are you try to do?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to count the distance between a character, and its container is by adding an inline element before the text, then substract the left offset of the parent from the placeholder (using [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)).

Example (**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/LM8xL/**)

HTML:

```
<div id="some-div" style='text-align: center; width: 300px'>test me</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $elem = $("#some-div"),     // Select element
    $placeholder = $("<span>"); // Create inline placeholder
$elem.prepend($placeholder);    // Add placeholder before its contents

// Calculate distance
var distance = $placeholder.offset().left - $elem.offset().left;
$placeholder.remove();          // Remove placeholder
alert(distance);                // Example: Display result
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working in Chrome. My guess is that the span needs inline-block http://jsfiddle.net/juandopazo/Nnt3u/

Comment: @juandopazo Thanks for your contribution. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrap your text with another element (`span`) and compare it's `.offsetLeft` with your `div`'s?

Answer (score 0):

As Kalashnikov said you need to wrap your text in a span tag but some extra work needs to be done. You need to get the span position and the parent (div) offset and subtract them to get the answer. Here is the code:

```
var position = $("span").position();
var parentOffset = $("span").parent().offset();
var left = position.left - parentOffset.left;
```